# Why won't Thunderbird shutdown? Instead it hangs?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, thunderbird

This issue seems to have been floating around for a long time on various support forums, but I've yet to find a definitive resolution. I've upgraded Mozilla Thunderbird at least once or twice without the issue being resolved. I love T-bird but this is a total pain in the ass.

If I quite Thunderbird, it starts to quit, but then it hangs with the "Application Not Responding" message. I have to force quit it every time. Same thing if I try to shut down.

My details:

- **OS**: Mac 10.6.8 Thunderbird: 7.0.1
- **Active T-Bird extensions**: Lightning 1.0b7, Provider for Google Calendar 0.8
- **Disabled T-Bird extensions** (in case this matters): Edit HTML 0.2.3.4, Mail Tweak 1.0pre10